# Combining static and animated plotly objects using subplot

Tags: r, animation, plotly, r-plotly

Given the following data.frame

```
data <- structure(list(
  a = c(3.022210021321, 3.31806778755904, 3.34379454984061, 3.47242836124846, 3.55604033866356, 1.11199792191451, 1.24063173332236, 1.31781202016707, 1.30494863902628, 1.3692655447302, 1.07983946906255, 1.2084732804704, 1.40142399758216, 1.60723809583472, 1.64582823925707), 
  b = c(2.64027979608152, 2.79483009168741, 2.90522315997732, 3.08185206924119, 2.86106593266136, 0.653204566863006, 0.697361794178973, 0.67528318052099, 0.653204566863006, 0.697361794178973, 2.06623584097395, 2.28702197755379, 2.48572950047564, 2.72859425071346, 2.77275147802942), 
  c = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  d = c(1.16264425026133, 1.16264425026133, 1.16264425026133, 1.16264425026133, 1.16264425026133, 1.48373054411498, 1.48373054411498, 1.48373054411498, 1.48373054411498, 1.48373054411498, 3.35362520562369, 3.35362520562369, 3.35362520562369, 3.35362520562369, 3.35362520562369), 
  e = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L), 
  f = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), 
  h = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("low", "mid", "high"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

and the following code snippet

```
library(plotly)    
p <- data %>% plot_ly(
  x = ~a, 
  y = ~b, 
  size = ~c, 
  sizes = c(100, 850),
  color = ~d, 
  colors = "YlOrRd",
  alpha = 0.365,
  frame = ~e, 
  text = ~paste0("Info: ", f),
  hoverinfo = "text",
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_text(textfont = list(size = 10, color = "black"), textposition = "top", text=~f, showlegend = F)

legend.plot <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_markers(x = 1, 
              y = seq_len(length(unique(data$c))),
              size = sort(unique(data$c)),
              showlegend = F, 
              color = I("black"),
              marker = list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area")) %>%
  layout(
    annotations = list(
      list(x = 1.2, 
           y = 0.4, 
           text = "Size by: c", 
           showarrow = F, 
           xref='paper', 
           yref='paper')),
    xaxis = list(
      zeroline=F,
      showline=F,
      showticklabels=F,
      showgrid=F),
    yaxis=list(
      side = "right",
      range = c(0,10),
      showgrid=F,
      zeroline=F,
      tickmode = "array",
      tickvals = seq_len(length(unique(data$c))),
      ticktext = c("low","mid","high")))

subplot(p, legend.plot, widths = c(0.85, 0.15), titleX=TRUE, titleY=TRUE) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = F) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Color by: d", x = 0.9, y = 1)
```

I manage to almost get a plotly plot that I want (ignoring the warnings along the way for now).

I am, however, unable to figure out, how to make the legend for size to stay during the animation. It appears in the initial stage, before the play button is hit, but as soon as I press play, it goes away.

So the static plot data points are disappearing from the subplot when I run the animation. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. The reason that your pseudo-legend disappears is that you only have it for the first frame. What I did here is adding the data for all the 5 years (that's why I have `rep`) and making sure that `frame` is included in both plots.

```r
legend.plot <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_markers(x = rep(1,15), 
              y = rep(seq_len(length(unique(data$c))),5),
              size = rep(sort(unique(data$c)),5),
              showlegend = F, 
              color = I("black"),
              frame = ~data$e,
              marker = list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area")) %>%
  layout(
    annotations = list(
      list(x = 1.2, 
           y = 0.4, 
           text = "Size by: c", 
           showarrow = F, 
           xref='paper', 
           yref='paper')),
    xaxis = list(
      zeroline=F,
      showline=F,
      showticklabels=F,
      showgrid=F),
    yaxis=list(
      side = "right",
      range = c(0,10),
      showgrid=F,
      zeroline=F,
      tickmode = "array",
      tickvals = seq_len(length(unique(data$c))),
      ticktext = c("low","mid","high")))
```

Comment: Interestingly, you say "pseudo-legend". Do you mean there is a better way to display legend for this context?

Comment: @Patrik_P Well it's not "the" legend! it's another plot that you combine it with your animated one using `subplot`. Isn't it? TBH, I cannot think of a better way but I can think of annotating circles of different size instead of using `add_markers` which is harder but it will stay the same during the animation. I know it serves as the legend. By pseudo-legend I meant it's not the default legend of plotly.